# payment completion from order history page in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6

I had changed the default prestashop payment workflow like payment of a order can be completed from order history page by creating a button in the order history where the user can proceed to the gateway.
In the payment gateway it is like straightforward, completing payment with cart details and total elements.

```
$address = new Address((int)$this->context->cart->id_address_invoice);
$address_state =  new State($address->id_state);
$customer = new Customer($this->context->cart->id_customer);
$amount = $this->context->cart->getOrderTotal();
```

so $amount is coming zero because I am not entering it into the cart. My question is how I pass the current order id(stored in ParentOrderController.php), so I can fetch and pass the details to gateway and total amount then update the order instead of create?